# Can't enter password when retrieving mail with mu4e

Tags: mu4e

I am setting up mu4e with offlineIMAP. 
I haven't written my password in any dot file so I have to enter it manually.
I can retrieve email from the console via `offlineimap` but when I try it from within emacs I can't make it work.
My `.emacs` file contains

```
(setq
   mu4e-get-mail-command "offlineimap"
   mu4e-update-interval nil)

(setq                         ;;for faster indexing see manual
  mu4e-index-cleanup nil      ;; don't do a full cleanup check
  mu4e-index-lazy-check t)    ;; don't consider up-to-date dirs
```

how to reproduce:

```
open emacs  
M-x mu4e-update-mail-and-index  
a) type 123abc enter
   letters trigger 'a is undefined', ...
   enter opens tutorial
b) click inside the '*mu4e-update*' buffer, type 123abc enter
   letters trigger 'a is undefined', ...
   enter triggers 'Buffer is read-only: #<buffer  *mu4e-update*>'
c) click inside minibuffer that says '[mu4e] Retrieving mail... |'
   *Messages* buffer gains focus
   type 123abc enter behaves as b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue so I filed an issue https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/1329 and I got it working using the following in my ~/.emacs file

```
(setq mu4e~get-mail-password-regexp "^Enter password for account 'Remote': $")
```

You have to make sure that this regexp will match the password prompt.